# How can I add text boxes using tkinter-python in front of the buttons that when I click them, the results should be displayed on the added text boxes

Tags: python, image, function, tkinter, button

I have developed a simple app in python using Tkinter-python where the select image navigates any folder with images. Method 1 and 2 buttons are having two different functions that analyze the selected image from the folder/path. I want to add two text boxes in front of the method 1 and 2 such that when I click method 1, the result should be printed on the added textbox 1 right after method 1 likewise on the second button. And if possible an addition of a function that selects images from the path on the 'Select Image' button will be acknowledged. Let that method 1 is a function that converts an image from RGB to gray and method two is a function that binarizes an RGB image.
Here are some codes for building the app.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog

class application(Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.minsize(width=500,height=500)
        self.initialize()
    
    def initialize(self):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
    
    
    #Button widgets
    ###########################################################################################
      self.button1 = Button(self,text='Button1',width=10,height=2)
      self.button1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='W',pady=5)
    
      self.button2 = Button(self,text='Result1',width=10,height=2)
      self.button2.grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='E',pady=5)
    
      self.button3 = Button(self,text='Result2',width=10,height=2)
      self.button3.grid(column=1,row=4,sticky='E',pady=5)
    
      self.button4 = Button(self,text='Exit',width=10,height=2,command=self.destroy)
      self.button4.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='W',pady=5)
    
      #Text widget for inserting results
    ############################################################################################
      self.text1 = Text(self,height=20,width=60,state=NORMAL)
      self.text1.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='W',padx=5)
    
      #Label widget
    ############################################################################################
      self.label1 = Label(self,text="Window",width=10,height=2,anchor="w")
      self.label1.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='E',padx=5)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = application(None)
    #font.nametofont('TkDefaultFont').configure(size=10)
    app.title("John's work")
    app.mainloop()
```

The resulting app from the codes above is shown through this figure
[image]

The expected one is as follows
[image]

Comment: The results are outside the window?

Comment: They should be in the window, we can either shift method 1 and 2 just 5 steps back so that the results should be in the window. Or any idea that may help to solve the problem is ok. I am new to this Tkinter especially oop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` has a class called `Toplevel` that you may find useful. It's a lot like a `Tk` object, except it can have one as a parent. Lots of people use `Toplevel` for things like popups. In your case, a function can be defined for creating a popup that displays text, like the example below:

```
from tkinter import *

def create_popup(parent, message):
    window = Toplevel(parent)
    label = Label(window, text = message)
    label.pack()
    button = Button(window, text = "Ok", command = window.destroy)
    button.pack()
    window.mainloop()

root = Tk()
temp = lambda: create_popup(root, "Hello")
button = Button(root, text = "Click me", command = temp)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If you decide the location and size of your main window beforehand with `Tk.geometry()`, you can easily make your popup right next to the buttons you mentioned. This means the code snippet above can be tweaked:

```
from tkinter import *

def create_popup(parent, message, configuration):
    window = Toplevel()
    window.geometry(configuration)
    label = Label(window, text = message)
    label.pack()
    button = Button(window, text = "Ok", command = window.destroy)
    button.pack()
    window.mainloop()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200+100+100")
temp = lambda: create_popup(root, "Hello", "50x50+350+100")
button = Button(root, text = "Click me", command = temp)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this was helpful!